# Handling NaN values while inserting Pandas dataframes into BigQuery tables

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I'm using the following code to insert a Pandas dataframe with multiple `NaN` values into a BigQuery table. The dataframe is prepared in cloud Datalab.

```
import google.datalab.bigquery as bq

bqtable = ('project_name', 'dataset_name', 'table_name')
table = bq.Table(bqtable)

table_schema = bq.Schema.from_data(df)
table.create(schema = table_schema, overwrite = True)

table.insert(df)
```

I'm getting the following error because of the `NaN` values in the dataframe:

```
RequestException: HTTP request failed: Invalid JSON payload received. 
Unexpected token. : "user_id": NaN,
                               ^
```

I know that `JSON` does not understand `NaN` but I can't just use `fillna` to convert those `NaN` values to something else as I need to have those fields inserted as `null` in the BigQuery table. 
Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 4):

Replace all `np.nan` values with python's `None` value, then re-run your code (or try `df.to_gbq`):

```
df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
```

I'm not experienced with Google BigQuery and I see nothing wrong with your existing code, but it may be worth installing the `pandas-gbq` package. Then try to write the DataFrame to GBQ with `df.to_gbq`, as detailed in the docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq.html

Answer (score 0):

If you meant NULL column like this:

[image]

Can you try changing the column type to FLOAT if possible?

[image]

Although this does add a tailing .0 to your user_id, but queries shouldn't be affected by it, unless your user_id is set as a string type.